# Soap Premature end

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i'm trying to write a php soap server
but i keep getting the folow error on louding the wsdl file:

```
WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'files.wsdl' : Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2
```

the wsdl file looks like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions name="TemperatureService"
     targetNamespace="http://www.mysite.com/soap/files.wsdl"
     xmlns:tns="http://www.mysite.com/soap/files.wsdl"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

        <!------------------------
                        DATATYPES
        ------------------------->
        <types>
        </types>

        <!------------------------
                        MESSAGES
        ------------------------->
        <message name="createReleaseRequest">
            <part name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <part name="size" type="xsd:string"/>
            <part name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>
        <message name="createReleaseResponse">
            <part name="rlsid" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>

        <!------------------------
                        PORTTYPES
        ------------------------->
        <portType name="DBPortType">
            <operation name="createRelease">
                <input message="tns:createReleaseRequest" />
                <output message="tns:createReleaseResponse" />
            </operation>
        </portType>
     </definitions>
```

and the php file:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SoapServer("files.wsdl");
$server->setClass("handleDB");
$server->handle();

class handleDB {
 ////
}
?>
```

does amyone know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Is there any space left at the first line of XML declaration in wsdl file? If so Please remove it. Also try to directly call this wsdl file via browser. I found XML parsing errors due to comments inside wsdl file. Try to remove them and test once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem
i could not type my comments i that way